# flutter_cache_manager is incompatible with all of the other dependencies

Tags: firebase, flutter, dependencies, qr-code, flutter-dependencies

I'm having a dilemma in solving the last part of my app where I want to save my qr code into the firebase, however, flutter_cache_manager dependencies just won't cooperate with the other dependencies, I tried to override but it didn't solve much, I don't want to change any dependencies as I have taken a long time to make sure it does not ruin my 3 weeks worth of progress, pls help

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  image_picker: ^0.7.3
  line_awesome_flutter: ^1.0.1
  flutter_screenutil: ^1.0.2
  animated_theme_switcher: ^1.0.5
  firebase_auth: ^1.4.1
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.4
  firebase_core: ^1.0.3
  flutter_local_notifications: ^0.6.0
  path_provider: ^0.5.0+1
  razorpay_flutter: ^1.2.1
  toast: ^0.1.5
  flutter_colorpicker: ^0.4.0
  flutter_barcode_scanner:
  barcode_widget: ^1.5.0
  firebase_storage: ^0.3.0
  intl:
  image_downloader:
  firebase_database:
  flutter_cache_manager: ^2.0.0
```

and the result shows this

```
Because flutter_cache_manager >=2.1.2 <3.0.0-nullsafety.0 depends on path_provider >=1.6.18 <3.0.0 and flutter_cache_manager >=2.0.0-beta <2.1.2 depends on path_provider ^1.6.18, flutter_cache_manager >=2.0.0-beta <3.0.0-nullsafety.0 requires path_provider >=1.6.18 <3.0.0.
So, because projectx depends on both path_provider ^0.5.0+1 and flutter_cache_manager ^2.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because projectx depends on both path_provider ^0.5.0+1 and flutter_cache_manager ^2.0.0, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **flutter_cache_manager: ^2.1.2**

In the dependency versions page https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager/versions you have all the versions available.

Or update your dependencies. Shouldn´t be that bad. Backup you dependency version list, and if your code stops working, try to fix it with the help of changelog page. If you can´t fix the issue, you can roll back to your old dependency version number.

[image]